# How can I stop jumping of components on load?

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, tailwind-css

I have a image error boundary component. Pretty simple, that while the image is being fetched displays a skeleton. Everything works as intended except while the skeleton is rendered the error div seems to render further down the page, the when the image renders, the skeleton disappears and the image jumps up. Any Tailwind pros can help me out here, I want there to be no jumping as in the image renders exactly where the skeleton was (Same height, width and position).

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Footer from "~/components/footer/footer";
import Header from "~/components/header/header";

export default function ErrorBoundary() {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [randomNumber, setRandomNumber] = useState<number>();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!randomNumber) {
      setRandomNumber(Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1))
    }
  }, [randomNumber])

  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <div className="flex flex-col items-center justify-between text-center h-80 w-80">
        <div className="">
          {
            randomNumber && <img className="h-40 w-40" src={`https://robohash.org/${randomNumber}?set=set4`} alt='catLoader' onLoad={() => {
              setLoading(false)
            }} />
          }
          {loading &&
            <div role="status" className="animate-pulse md:space-y-0 md:space-x-8 md:flex md:items-center">
              <div className="flex items-center justify-center w-40 h-40 bg-gray-300 rounded sm:w-96 dark:bg-gray-700">
                <svg className="w-40 h-40 text-gray-200 dark:text-gray-600" aria-hidden="true" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 18">
                  <path d="M18 0H2a2 2 0 0 0-2 2v14a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h16a2 2 0 0 0 2-2V2a2 2 0 0 0-2-2Zm-5.5 4a1.5 1.5 0 1 1 0 3 1.5 1.5 0 0 1 0-3Zm4.376 10.481A1 1 0 0 1 16 15H4a1 1 0 0 1-.895-1.447l3.5-7A1 1 0 0 1 7.468 6a.965.965 0 0 1 .9.5l2.775 4.757 1.546-1.887a1 1 0 0 1 1.618.1l2.541 4a1 1 0 0 1 .028 1.011Z" />
                </svg>
              </div>
              <span className="sr-only">Fetching a cat picture...</span>
            </div>
          }
        </div>
        <h1 className='text-7xl text-secondary-300 align-bottom'>Coming Soon!</h1>
      </div>
      <Footer />
    </>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can put your skeleton image in an images folder and use it as the initial state of the current img element and after fetching your cat image, change its state to the new url you got or you can use setTimeout to add some delay and to get the loading effect before setting loading state to false.
You can do something like :
https://codesandbox.io/s/small-bash-hdqhk9?file=/src/components/ImageLoading.tsx:0-828

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Img from "../images/default.svg";

export default function ImageLoading() {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [imgUrl, setImgUrl] = useState("");
  const [randomNumber, setRandomNumber] = useState(
    Math.floor(Math.random() * 100 + 1)
  );
  useEffect(() => {
    const id = setTimeout(() => {
      if (randomNumber) {
        setImgUrl(`https://robohash.org/${randomNumber}?set=set4`);
        setLoading(false);
      }
    }, 200);
    return () => clearTimeout(id);
  }, [randomNumber]);

  return (
    <div>
      {loading ? (
        <div>
          <img src={Img} alt="catLoader" />
          <br />
          <small>Loading images...</small>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <img src={imgUrl} alt="catLoader" />
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

I hope this can help you.